# How do I install a released, scoped package before it's published?

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, yarnpkg, package.json

As of this writing, the current version of `@babel/core` [published to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/core/v/7.2.2) is 7.2.2.  The latest "release" version of babel on [github](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases) is 7.3.1, which contains several fixes I'm interested in.

What is the correct syntax to install the latest github version of `@babel/core` via `package.json`?     I tried

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "github:babel/babel#v7.3.1"
  }
```

and some variations thereof but those gave me "invalid package version".  I think I'm confused about how to deal with the @scope syntax?

Comment: `git+https://git@github.com/babel/babel.git#v7.3.1`

Comment: Same thing, `invalid package version`.  That would normally work with traditional packages, but since this is a scoped repo with a bunch of subrepros (`@babel/core`, `@babel/cli` etc) I'm not sure it can be referenced directly..?

Comment: `@babel/core` is still `7.2.2` which is not the same as `babel 7.3.1` as fixes/updates in `7.3.1` do not relate to 7.2.2 of `babel/core` - `babel/cli` is only updated with `7.2.3` - you can see from the commit messages here `https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages`

Comment: `@babel/core` is only related to `7.2.2` - and has not been updated to `7.3.1`... it looks like `7.3.1` is related to `babel-helpers`/`babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread`, `babel-preset-env`...

Comment: *facepalm* yep you're right.  and `7.2.2` references versions `^7.2.2` for other components, so `7.3.1` is already installed.  Thanks for the assist @DenisTsoi!

Comment: I'll add an answer to help confirm ~ :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 26 Jan 2019 -
`@babel/core` is released as `7.2.2`,
therefore, there is an `invalid package version` when installing `git+https://git@github.com/babel/babel.git#v7.3.1`.

the relevant packages for `7.3.1`
would be `babel-helpers`/`babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` and `babel-preset-env`,
which you would have to install separately from `@babel/core`

The discrepancy between `@babel/core` version
and other packages is to ensure modularity of packages within the `@babel` team.

Comment: The short of it -- even though babel is a given version, the other sub-components of babel may have more recent minor / patch versions.